HP Laptop Mic Button LED Always On
The mic mute button light (orange LED) on the F8 key is always on. I am an absolute Linux beginner. Although the mic button can mute and unmute the microphone, the issue is with the LED light on the button staying on. How can I solve this?
Laptop Model: HP EliteBook 840 G6

I created a local .hwdb file with correct mapping in /etc/udev/hwdb.d/61-hp-mic-mute-hotkey.hwdb:
# see also: /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb
evdev:atkbd:dmi:bvn*:bvr*:bd*:svnHewlett-Packard*:pn*EliteBook*:pvr*
KEYBOARD_KEY_81=f20                          # Fn+F8 on Elitebook, map to F20
# KEYBOARD_KEY_81=fn_esc                      # org entry

then generated a new /lib/udev/hwdb.bin file and reloaded it with:
sudo udevadm -d hwdb --update; sudo udevadm -d control --reload; sudo udevadm trigger

Didn't work.

There's an answer at AskUbuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138067/turn-off-the-mic-mute-button-light-on-hp-elitebook-840 . BTW, the question is clear, not sure why Bot made comment.

@DrMoishePippik I have tried that. It didn't worked for me.


I have tried that. It didn't worked for me.* If so make sure to [edit] your question to include detailed information about EVERYTHING you tried, the expected result(s) and what happened instead. "Absolute beginner" is moot after saying "have tried that" and please don't reply to bot!


What items do you have under /sys/class/leds? Is there a platform::micmute subdirectory? What does the platform::micmute/trigger file contain? Does echoing 0 into platform::micmute/brightness disable the LED?

@ChanganAuto Edited. Please check now.

@grawity /sys/class/leds contains:
hanar97@debian:~$ ls /sys/class/leds
input0::capslock  input0::numlock  input0::scrolllock  phy0-led
hanar97@debian:~$
no platform::micmue

Which kernel version (uname -r) are you running? These things are often wired up individually for each laptop model (I had to send a few kernel patches for the touchpad and mute LEDs of my 840 G4).

@grawity It is 6.1.0-28-amd64. I installed fedora and arch somedays ago. All with the same problem.

Do you have any way to test 6.8.x or later (which includes this change)? e.g. from Debian 'bookworm-backports' or from a recent Arch?

@grawity I installed Arch Linux (maybe 5-6 days ago), but the issue with the mic mute LED was still present. I’ve since uninstalled it. Should I check bookworm-backports also?
